# I want users to upload an image and then give a title with it so they can give the image a name

Tags: php, tags, backend

I have a function where people can upload images to my website but I want them to give a title, tag and description with it. I made a modal for the images. So if  a users clicks on a image I want them to see the title, tag and description what the user gave with it.

I have tried stuff with help of my friend but we both don't know how it works. Ill be happy with someones help.

This is currently what i have for the image upload

```
    <?php
    //Start connection to the localhost server
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    if ($conn) {
    echo "<br />";
    } else  {
    die("". mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    //Select Database
    $selectalreadycreateddatabase = mysqli_select_db($conn, "uploaddisplay");
    if ($selectalreadycreateddatabase) {
    echo "<br />";
    } else {
    echo "<br />";
    $createNewDb = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `uploaddisplay`";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $createNewDb)) {
    echo "<br />";
    $selectCreatedDatabase = mysqli_select_db($conn, "uploaddisplay");
    if ($selectCreatedDatabase) {
    echo "<br />";
    // Creating new table
    $sqlcreatetable = "
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `updis` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
    ";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqlcreatetable)) {
    echo "<br />";
    } else {
    echo "<br />";
    }
    }
    } else {
    echo "<br />";
    }
    }
    //If submit button is clicked
    if(isset($_POST['fileuploadsubmit'])) {
    $fileupload = $_FILES['fileupload']['name'];
    $fileuploadTMP = $_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'];
    //This is the folder where images will be saved.
    $folder = "images/";
    move_uploaded_file($fileuploadTMP, $folder.$fileupload);
    //Insert image details into `updis` table
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `updis`(`name`) VALUES ('$fileupload')";
    $qry = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if ($qry) {
    echo "<br />";
    }
    }
    //Select all data from `updis` table
    $select = " SELECT * FROM `updis` " ;
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $select) ;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $image = $row['name'];
    //Display image from the database
    echo '<img src="images/'.$image.'" height="300" width="300" >';
    }
    //close connection
    if (mysqli_close($conn)) {
    echo "<br />";
    }
    ?>
```

This lets me upload a picture and saves it in my database

**Form:**

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <input type="file" name="fileupload"/> <input type="submit" name="fileuploadsubmit" value="Upload"/><br> </form> </div> <div class="modal-footer"> 

<form> <label for="name">Title</label> 
<input type="text" id="name1" name="name" required> 
</form>
```

Comment: CREATE DB everytime? add title, desc fields in your form and get the values by using `$_POST`... where is your form?

Comment: This is my form but I want the function first if possible.


      <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="fileupload"/>
      <input type="submit" name="fileuploadsubmit" value="Upload"/><br>

      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <form>
      <label for="name">Title</label>
     <input type="text" id="name1" name="name" required>
   </form>

Comment: why are u using 2 forms here? u need to use input field in your first form